# "you can have a meal." or "you can have meal."

Tags: indefinite-article

I'm reading an English vocabulary book, in the book there are the following sentences:

> - you can have breakfast.
> - you can have lunch.
> - you can have dinner.
> - you can have **a** meal.

Why do use article (a) with *meal* and don't use it with other words?

Should/shouldn't using it with: snack, supper, brunch, sandwich, coffee, drink, ice cream  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can use an article with the other words.  Here's [**a** breakfast of tortillas](https://books.google.com/books?id=yGpFCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA79&dq=%22a%20breakfast%20of%22&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q=%22a%20breakfast%20of%22&f=false), here's [**a** filling lunch](https://books.google.com/books?id=cm7n8jtjgOAC&lpg=PT135&dq=%22a%20filling%20lunch%22&pg=PT135#v=onepage&q=%22a%20filling%20lunch%22&f=false), here's [I once hosted **a** dinner](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rv-xJDfXSqQC&lpg=PT37&dq=%22a%20dinner%20at%22&pg=PT37#v=onepage&q=%22a%20dinner%20at%22&f=false).  The use of the article here is more or less the same as it is anywhere else: it indicates a specific example of something as opposed to the general concept or phenomenon.

A lot of food terms are non-count nouns or can be used in a non-count sense, for example *coffee*:

- [I like coffee](https://books.google.com/books?id=NdJhtuFMpeUC&lpg=PA74&dq=%22i%20like%20coffee%22&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=%22i%20like%20coffee%22&f=false) (coffee as a general idea or unspecified quantity)
- [I ordered a coffee](https://books.google.com/books?id=juFWDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP5&dq=%22i%20ordered%20a%20coffee%22&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q=%22i%20ordered%20a%20coffee%22&f=false) (a specific order or quantity of coffee)

It's a matter of learning which words are used in a mass noun sense and which aren't.  For example, *breakfast*, *lunch*, *dinner*, *supper*, *brunch*, *coffee*, and *ice cream* are usually mass nouns because they refer to general phenomena or materials, but it's also perfectly acceptable to refer to (for example) [**a** brunch](https://books.google.com/books?id=Br_1BFWabuEC&lpg=PA17&dq=%22a%20brunch%22&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brunch%22&f=false) if you're referring to a specific one.

*Sandwich* is not a general phenomenon or material, but a discrete object, so it's always "I had **a** sandwich", never "I had sandwich."  Likewise, *meal* is not a phenomenon or a material, but a specific thing, so it's always **a** meal (when it means "a specific instance of having food"...[there's also a definition of *meal* that means "ground-up seeds", and that one is a mass noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meal).)

Drink is a little bit of an odd case, because it's normally a count noun if it refers to "specific things to drink" ([let's have a drink](https://books.google.com/books?id=-XYaOXAqvmYC&lpg=PA127&dq=%22let's%20have%20a%20drink%22&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20have%20a%20drink%22&f=false) or [let's have drinks](https://books.google.com/books?id=fu97BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT276&dq=%22let's%20have%20drinks%22&pg=PT276#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20have%20drinks%22&f=false)) but a mass noun if you mean "things to drink in general" or "alcohol" (["attitudes relating to food and drink"](https://books.google.com/books?id=KDBuBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA5&dq=%22food%20and%20drink%22&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=%22food%20and%20drink%22&f=false)).

Comment: Good answer! I’d say that _ice cream_ is a peculiar case, too. I’d normally say: _You can have ice cream_, but I might use _**an** ice cream_ if the ice cream truck was passing by, I was referring to something like one of [these](http://www.goodhumor.com/Images/519/519-114278-Homepage_Hero_Variety_620x511.png).

Comment: @J.R. - Good point about *ice cream*.  I remember we had a question here before once about "a fried rice" too, and I sometimes wonder if English is moving in the direction of making all nouns countable with the sense of "an order of X" or if it was always that way.

Comment: No reason to suppose that English is moving in the direction of making all nouns countable. This use of the article has been happening for a long time; compare Chaucer *Which of yow..that telleth in this caas Tales of best sentence and moost solaas Shal haue **a soper** at oure aller cost.*

Answer (score 0):

We use or don't use the article depending on the meaning of the word.

When the reference is to the meal that normally occurs at a particular time of day, there is no article:

> We eat breakfast in the morning.
>
> We eat lunch around mid-day.
>
> We eat dinner in the evening.

The article is used when we refer to a particular instance of such a meal, or to a particular kind of such a meal, such as one with a particular main course, or a particular type of preparation

> ...a breakfast of bacon and eggs
>
> She only had time for a quick breakfast—a cup of coffee and a piece of toast

or one that celebrates a particular occasion

> a dinner in his honor
>
> Roast lamb makes an excellent Easter dinner

Any sort of particularization licenses the use of the article.